# Changing the row background color of a QTreeView does not work

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` and want different background colors for rows, depending on their content. To achieve this, I derived a `class MyTreeView` from `QTreeView` and implemented the paint method as follows:

```
    void MyTreeView::drawRow (QPainter* painter,
                              const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                              const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
      QStyleOptionViewItem newOption(option);

      if (someCondition)
      {
        newOption.palette.setColor( QPalette::Base, QColor(255, 0, 0) );
        newOption.palette.setColor( QPalette::AlternateBase, QColor(200, 0, 0) );
      }
      else
      {
        newOption.palette.setColor( QPalette::Base, QColor(0, 0, 255) );
        newOption.palette.setColor( QPalette::AlternateBase, QColor(0, 0, 200) );
      }

      QTreeView::drawRow(painter, newOption, index);
    }
```

Initially, I set `setAlternatingRowColors(true);` for the QTreeView.

**My problem:** Setting the color for **QPalette::Base has no effect**. Every second row remains white.

However, setting **QPalette::AlternateBase works as expected**.
I tried `setAutoFillBackground(true)` and `setAutoFillBackground(false)` without any effect.

Are there any hints how to solve this problem? Thank you.

---

*Remark:* Setting the color by adapting `MyModel::data(const QModelIndex&, int role)` for `Qt::BackgroundRole` does not provide the desired result. In this case, the background color is used only for a part of the row. But I want to color the full row, including the left side with the tree navigation stuff.

*Qt Version:* 4.7.3

---

**Update:**
For unknown reasons `QPalette::Base` seems to be opaque.
setBrush does not change that.
I found the following workaround:

```
    if (someCondition)
    {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, Qt::red);
        newOption.palette.setBrush( QPalette::AlternateBase, Qt::green);
    }
    else
    {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, Qt::orange);
        newOption.palette.setBrush( QPalette::AlternateBase, Qt:blue);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

If the only problem is that the expanding/collapsing controls do not have a background like rest of the row then use `Qt::BackgroundRole` in `::data()` of your model (as described by [pnezis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007407/pnezis) in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256644/2642204)) and add this to your tree view class:

```
void MyTreeView::drawBranches(QPainter* painter,
                              const QRect& rect,
                              const QModelIndex& index) const
{
  if (some condition depending on index)
    painter->fillRect(rect, Qt::red);
  else
    painter->fillRect(rect, Qt::green);

  QTreeView::drawBranches(painter, rect, index);
}
```

I've tested this on Windows (Vista and 7) using Qt 4.8.0 and expanding/collapsing arrows have proper background. The problem is that those arrows are part of the view and thus cannot be handled in a model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said, the drawback of this solution is that it is scattered between Model and View. But the idea with `fillRect` lead me to a reasonable workaround.

Comment: I agree, in this case it might be better to have coloring code only in the view - overriding other drawXXX member functions. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of subclassing `QTreeView` you should handle the background color through your model. Use the [`data()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) function and the [`Qt::BackgroundRole`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) for changing the background color of the rows.

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
   if (!index.isValid())
      return QVariant();

   if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
   {
       if (condition1)
          return QColor(Qt::red);
       else
          return QColor(Qt::green); 
   }

   // Handle other roles

   return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but this does not yield desired result. With this approach, the background color is not painted for the full row, but only for the tree items itself. The background of the tree navigation (on the left side of the items) is not changed.

Comment: @SebastianK I think this is still the right way, but the way you implement `condition1` in this example is the key. For example, you could do `if( index.sibling( index.row(), someColumnIndex ).data() == whatever ) { ... }`. You have to make sure this is not called for the case where `index.column() == someColumnIndex` as of infinite recursion of course.

Comment: @TimMeyer I tried that with `condition1` beeing always true. The background of the row was only partially red. For expanded items, the left part of the row is still white. With "left part" I mean the area with the tree navigation stuff (expanding/collapsing [+]/[-] and the line to parent)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/4702439

```
if ( const QStyleOptionViewItemV4* opt = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionViewItemV4*>(&option) )
{
        if (opt.features & QStyleOptionViewItemV4::Alternate)
            painter->fillRect(option.rect,option.palette.alternateBase());
        else
            painter->fillRect(option.rect,painter->background());
}
```